# Getting a nearby input element when clicking on a span (onclick event)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a nearby input element with the closest() function, but it says clostest is not a function...

Here is a JSFidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/1mvc76fv/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="1"/>
    <span onClick="fireIt(this)">Kick</span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" value="2"/>
    <span onClick="fireIt(this)">Kick</span>
</div>`
```

JS:

```
window.fireIt =  function(param) {
    tmp = param.closest('input');
    alert( tmp.val() );  
}
```

How to get the closest input element? Why is closest not working?

Comment: Use siblings() or prev() instead of closest () function

Comment: I'm not trying to be facetious, or even facile, but often when you have a problem - or unexpected result from use of a jQuery method - it's best to simply check the documentation. Which is itself pretty easy: `http://api.jquery.com/<method-name>/`, giving (in this case): [http://api.jquery.com/closest/](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) method to access the previous input

```
window.fireIt =  function(param) {
  tmp = $(param).prev('input');
  alert( tmp.val() );
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mvc76fv/1/)

---

Since you're already using jquery, you can use it to bind the event handler rather than using inline handlers as follows:

```
$("span").click(function() {
  tmp = $(this).prev('input');
  alert(tmp.val());
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you show how to bind events using jquery instead of inline event handler.